# JDeveloper Executable JAR file build takes almost 2 hours

Tags: java, executable-jar, jdeveloper

I had a question regarding JDeveloper's methodology for generating executable jar files.

I have tried several tutorials for building JAR files and finally found one that generates an executable jar file that i can run on a Linux system. Here is a link to it http://idlebrains.org/tutorials/java-tutorials/generating-executable-jar-file-third-party-library/

However, the building of the 5 MB file takes, on average, 1 hour and 40 min. I looked at the JAR file once it was built and it seems that all the libraries that i had included in my build were somehow decomposed into their component code. What I mean is that the libraries that i included in my build don't appear as .JAR files inside the executable JAR.

I have been looking into why it would take so long and why JDeveloper would not simply add the dependent JAR files in the executable JAR as simply JAR files. However I have not had much luck.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse can build jar files which you can then execute.

Right click on project -> export -> Java -> Runnable Jar File -> Select the Launch Configuration Corresponding to your Project -> Package Required Libraries in Generated JAR -> Select Export Destination -> Finish.

It should only take a couple minutes, tops.

Then, go to the JAR file, right click on it -> properties -> permissions -> allow executing file as program.

Now you should be able to run the JAR file by opening it with Java. If you wish to see console logs, open up the terminal and run "Java -jar location/to/jar/file.jar". Note that this method doesn't even require for the JAR file to be marked as executable.

Comment: Right, i came across other methods for using Eclipse, however, at work i can only use JDeveloper since it is the IDE that has been approved for use. I have been trying to get eclipse at work working but in the mean time i was trying to see what in and outs JDeveloper has

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for clarifying. I only use Eclipse and I have a couple friends who use Greenfoot, but I've never crossed paths with JDeveloper. You should certainly try to get approval for Eclipse. I'm especially concerned about what company would ever approve JDeveloper but not Eclipse? It's certainly a very good IDE.